# Flutter is there any way to make an dynamical timestamp that print something like 10 minute ago, 1 hour agor, or 2 month ago

Tags: android, flutter, timestamp, timeago

i already send my lastseen timestamp into firebase and how can i deduct the current timestamp with the one that i already sent to firestore. that will give me `Last Seen 15 minutes ago`, or maybe a long time that look like this `Last Seen 20 days ago` that did it. im already try to use the `timeago` package in pub.dev but i dont know what should i replace in the duration. the code look like this

```
final fifteenAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(minutes: 15));
```

what should i replace the minutes with ?

this is the data that i've been retrieve from firestore

```
I/flutter ( 6086): 2022-03-24 12:21:32.235192
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final DateTime lastSeen = DateTime.parse(yourDataFromFireStore);
final Duration timePassed = DateTime.now().difference(lastSeen);
```

The timePassed variable will then hold the duration that passed since it was last seen. You will then have to define a function that takes the duration and returns the proper string that should be displayed like for example "5 days ago" or something else.

Comment: the fromString didnt work `The method 'fromString' isn't defined for the type 'DateTime'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromString'.`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake it is: DateTime.parse(the data)

Comment: okok, letme try it hope its work

Comment: yeps its work. and i added timeago package to make the `5 days ago`